Google Sheets FLOOR Function provides different results to same situation
Date Set 1
Time IN - 5/19/2024, 16:00:00 (A3)
Time OUT - 5/20/2024, 00:30:00 (B3)
Duration: 8.50 (Cell C3)
Formula = (B3 - A3)*24

Date Set 2
Time IN - 5/29/2024 15:30:00 (A4)
Time OUT - 5/30/2024 0:00:00 (B4)
Duration: 8.50 (Cell C4)
Formula = (B4 - A4)*24
FLOOR(C3-8,0.5) = 0.5
FLOOR(C4-8,0.5) = 0.0
Why is the FLOOR function giving me different answers? I'm trying to calculate the overtime hours an employee worked for specific days.
I tried to look for similar problems, but didn't find an answer.

It works for me, however, when I enter the dates like you have here it is treating the dates as text and gives a #VALUE error when trying apply the formula (B4-A4)*24. If I enter the dates as 2024-05-29 16:00:00 it all works. I do notice that in your second set of dates you have no comma, but in the first you do. I am not sure about these date entries in Google Sheets

Possible floating point arithmetic irregularities. Try the round() for the subtraction part as such round(C3-8,2)

Hi Dave. It's a typo. But in the my sheets, the formatting are consistent, and they are all valid date values.

Thanks, rockinfreakshow for the pointing that out. Finally found the solution. It's definitely because of the floating point!

The floor() function always rounds numbers down, so you may end up with an unexpected result when a floating point number is marginally below some value.
To avoid the issue, use mround(), like this:
=mround(C3 / 24 - "8:00", "0:30")

To simplify the whole thing, omit the factor 24 to use proper durations instead of "digital hours", like this:



row
A
B
C
D




3
5/19/2024 16:00:00
5/20/2024 0:30:00
8:30:00 =B3 - A3
0:30:00 =mround(C3 - "8:00", "0:30")


4
5/29/2024 15:30:00
5/30/2024 0:00:00
8:30:00 =B4 - A4
0:30:00 =mround(C4 - "8:00", "0:30")



Format columns C:D as Format > Number > Duration.
See Working with date and time values in Google Sheets.
